# Стоит ли в данном случае ставить двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, двоеточие, правила

Стоит ли ставить двоеточие в приведённом ниже предложении-ворнинге?
В данном фильме присутствуют сцены, демонстрирующие(:) преступные деяния, насилие и жестокость, употребление запрещённых веществ.

Или же здесь двоеточие факультативно? Как предупреждение о том, что далее следует некое перечисление.
Спасибо.

Comment: Parry Gott, приветствую Вас! На этом сайте принято благодарить участников за полезные ответы, нажимая стрелочку (треугольник) вверх. Помимо этого, тот ответ, который более всего помог в решении вопроса, отмечается галочкой и становится принятым.

Comment: Не беспокойтесь, прекрасно об этом знаю, но (в виду малого рейтинга) ранее мои оценки не влияли на публичное отображения рейтинга (более чем уверен, что вы знаете об этой особенности сайта). О чём меня не забывал уведомлять появляющийся нотиф.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С точки зрения строгих правил двоеточие здесь неуместно.
***В данном фильме присутствуют сцены, демонстрирующие преступные деяния, насилие и жестокость, употребление запрещённых веществ.***

Сразу сниму вопрос о факультатиdности. Двоеточие факультативным не бывает. Есть случаи, когда с грехом пополам можно говорить о некой факультативности выбора между двоеточием и другими знаками (тире в первую очередь), но само по себе двоеточие к знакам, допускающим факультативность не относится, оно или требуется - или нет.

Здесь оно не требуется, поскольку нет обобщающего слова, предшествующего списку.
Другие мотивы постановки двоеточия полностью отсутствуют.
Тем не менее иногда встречается подобное оформление списков, без обобщающего слова, но с двоеточием. Это отступление от правил, которое можно как-то опрадать в случае построения списка по пунктам:

*В данном фильме присутствуют сцены, демонстрирующие:

преступные деяния,

насилие и жестокость,

употребление запрещённых веществ.*

Здесь в угоду лаконичности и наглядности обобщающее список слово как бы опускается. Повторю, это отступление от строгих правил, но в каком-то смысле оправданное.
При наборе же в строку даже такое зыбкое основание отсутствует.

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь момент с "предупреждением" стал прозрачно ясным.

Comment: @ParryGott посмотрите всё-таки еще ответ Sharon. Я не очень с ней согласен в том, как она трактует Розенталя, но для полноты картины это мнение надо учитывать. За её формулирровкой стоит по сути признание двоеточия в подобных случаях именно факультативным знаком.

Answer (score 2):

В данной теме можно использовать следующее правило Розенталя (п.3): http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103

3. Если однородным членам предложения не предшествует обобщающее слово (словосочетание), то перед ними двоеточие ставится только в том случае, когда **необходимо предупредить читателя,** что дальше следует перечисление:
   Из-под сена **виднелись**: самовар, кадка с мороженной формой и ещё какие-то привлекательные узелки и коробочки (Л. Т.); ***Тут были**: Павел, чухонец, штабс-капитан Ярошевич, фельдфебель Максименко, красная фуражка, дама с белыми зубами, доктор* (Ч.). Ср. в деловой и научной речи: На заседании присутствовали:…; Для получения смеси нужно взять:…; Роли исполняют:…; В ролях: …

Таким образом, это авторское решение, которое во многом зависит **от контекста**. Такое оформление уместно, к примеру,  в аннотации, в представлении фильма. При постановке двоеточия мы как бы **пропускаем обобщающее слово**, но оно должно быть понятным для автора и для читателя.

В устной речи в этомслучае делается **пауза**, предупреждающая о последующем перечислении.

Comment: Мне кажется, здесь такая трактовка неуместна. Нет никакой необходимости предупреждать читателя о том, что дальше идет список. Его совсем о другом предупреждают, нет?